# Get start and end epoch times for today

Tags: ruby, epoch

I'm using an API that requires a `start_time` and an `end_time` in epoch that will give me data between those times. The question is I want all the data from the start of UTC today to the end of UTC today.

What's the most effective way to do this in ruby?

Comment: Be wary of timezones, those on the remote API side as well as your own.  Hopefully, the API is sane enough to do everything in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ActiveSupport` `Date` functions [`#beginning_of_day`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/beginning_of_day) and [`#end_of_day`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/end_of_day). And use [`to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-to_i) to convert the time to seconds since *Epoch*.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

Date.today.beginning_of_day.to_i
# => 1395532800 
Date.today.end_of_day.to_i
# => 1395619199
```

Comment: Did you install the gem or use Rails ?

Answer (score 1):

`Date.today.to_time.to_i`

should get you the start, and

`(Date.today + 1).to_time.to_i`

should get you the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using rails or do not wish to import `require 'active_support/core_ext'` for some reason you can do it using ruby as follows

```
Date.today.to_time.to_i # beginning_of_day
=> 1481221800

Date.today.to_time.change(hour: 23, min: 59, sec: 59).to_i # end_of_day
=> 1481308199
```